# Best practice for PHP paths

Tags: php, path, twig

I have been all over the Internet trying to figure out the best way to handle paths in my website. Should I use relative paths, absolute paths?

I have seen dirname (**FILE**) mentioned several times. One problem I have with relative paths is that PHP files which are included by several other files at different directory levels cause the relative paths to break. For example if the directory structure is

```
Root
    A
    B
       b
```

And a PHP file in b and An include another file from B then the relative paths for the code in the file in B will be different.

So in general what is the best way to handle paths to files with regards to includes and file operations within the code.

Comment: That's the problem with "Best" anything, it's almost always subjective.

Answer (score 15):

Tho there are many ways to find out the path I always find it easiest to define a constant within a file on the root of the project `index.php` or a `config` of sort.
then I can use `SITE_ROOT` for includes/class loaders ect, and `SITE_URL` for views, controllers, redirects ect.

```
<?php
$root=pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
define ('BASE_FOLDER', basename($root['dirname']));
define ('SITE_ROOT',    realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define ('SITE_URL',    'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.BASE_FOLDER);
?>
```

**[Basic class Autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)**

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include (SITE_ROOT.'/includes/'.$class_name.'.php');
}
$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Comment: With this method, don't all the files that are going to use the autoloader need to include the config file.  IF so is the best way to do that using a relative path like include('../../config.php');  Also like I mentioned above, will this work if not all files are OO

Comment: define the constants in your index file, it just needs to point to your root, if your config is in the root then all you need todo is `include(SITE_ROOT.'/config.php')` regardless of how deep you call that include it will always point to the same file. the `__autoload` only works when calling classes, it save on doing `include (SITE_ROOT.'/includes/'.$class_name.'.php');
` for each class, its very handy for models in a MVC pattern as a controller is normally called from the router/front controller class

Comment: I don't quite understand how this fixes my problem.  Even if I have this config level in my root, then it still needs to be included using relative paths by all my other files.  An example of the problems I am having is that I have an ErrorReporter class that is included by all my other files which reside at different levels with in the directory structure.  Inside the ErrorReporter class I have some paths but if they are relative they become relative to whatever class is including ErrorReporter which means they aren't relative to the same spot every time.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your include files into one main directory. Then create a path variable in a config file or in the script itself, which points to the include directory.

Comment: This would work, but it breaks my organization. I am trying to keep my files in a logical directory structure because there are so many.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use proper naming conventions for the Directory Structure, PHP files and Class names of the file and the design a autoloader to include the file

Comment: Do you have any good links to examples of creating and autoloader, I am pretty new to php and haven't found a good tutorial yet.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Thanks, I read that but that seems to only work for OO, some of my files are not OO so I am guessing this method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The Zend framework has some good pointers about optimizing include paths:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/performance.classloading.html

Even if you're not using the Zend framework, these are good pointers. The general bulletpoints are:

- Use absolute paths
- Reduce the number of include paths you define
- Define the current directory last, or not at all
- Define your Zend Framework include_path as early as possible (not really relevant if you don't use Zend)

Answer (score -1):

New version of php (PHP5.3) is possible to use [__autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)
So, you just need to determine root of your application.

Comment: Does autoload scan the directory path recursively, and if it does that seems bad for performance.  Also it seems that autoload only works for Classes, some of my files are not OO.

Comment: And has been deprecated since [http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php](PHP 7.2).